# multiple occurence in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string in which I want to replace an occurence which I am not being able to achieve following is the code

```
var code="user_1/has some text and user_1? also has some text";
newcode=code.replace(/user_1//g,'_');
```

One more thing if i have to replace a string from another string how to do?
example.

```
var replacestring="user_1";
var code="user_1/some value here for some user";
var newcode=code.replace(/+replacestring+/g,'_');
```

Comment: There is only **one occurrence** of `user_1/` what should the output looked like?

Answer (score 1):

Escape the `/` in the regex using `\`

```
newcode=code.replace(/user_1\//g,'_');
```

For your comment

> @Vega I have another confusion. can i use a value in a string to pass
>   instead of user_1/ for replacement? what would be the syntax?

You can initialize RegEx object like below,

```
var userName = 'user_1/';
var newcode = code.replace(new RegExp(userName, 'g'), '_');
```

[Read More about RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score 1):

`/` is a special char thus needs to be escaped with `\` before it:

```
var code = "user_1/has some text and user_1? also has some text";
var newcode = code.replace(/user_1\//g, '_');
alert(newcode);​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/R4kM7/1)

if you want to replace all `user_1`, use this:

```
var code = "user_1/has some text and user_1? also has some text";
var newcode = code.replace(/user_1/g, '_');
alert(newcode);​
```

**[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R4kM7/)**

Comment: mm.. for sometime I thought I misunderstood the question.. as the title said multiple occurrence

Comment: @Vega. Yes, I'm confused as well...! so I added the two options.

Comment: True, I saw ur answer with `/g` first and thought OP made a typo and you were pointing it out. Lets see what OP is going to come back with. :)

Comment: @Vega I have another confusion. can i use a value in a string to pass instead of user_1/ for replacement? what would be the syntax?

Comment: @ManBehind Yes you can. >> http://jsfiddle.net/skram/R4kM7/2/ << It would be like `var userName = 'user_1/';
var newcode = code.replace(new RegExp(userName, 'g'), '_');`

Comment: @ManBehind My answer is below lol.. Good luck and Happy coding.